# Setting base_url through MySQL value before routing

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-routing

Is there any point in the execution of CodeIgniter where I can get data from MySQL through `HTTP_HOST` and use and set the `base_url` retrieved so that the correct routing is enforced?

I didn't have any problem with running this under the hook event `post_controller_constructor` when I only used *sub.domain.com* and *domain.com*, but I this problem when I wish to have `base_url` as *domain.com/folder/*.

My Codeigniter has already decided which controller to load, and changing the `base_url` doesn't fix it.

From my knowledge, I can't do MySQL commands before the hook event `post_controller_constructor`, which I guess I must be able to do since `base_url` should be set before routing occurs.

So basicly, is there any efficient way to either reroute in middle of the execution, or to run mysql before routing occurs?

[**CodeIgniter Hooks**](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/hooks.html)

**Update**
Seems like I was on the wrong track.

Here's the scenario:

I have one CodeIgniter package/set. At the moment I use it through multiple domains and subdomains. My CodeIgniter loads relevant profile based on `HTTP_HOST`. I've made it to also load relevant profile in case it contains a folder to the domain. The problem is that the routing occurs and see's the folder as a part of the controller/routing instead of the base_url.

With the address *http://domain.com/folder/admin* I want the controller `admin` loaded (inside `controllers/`), not the controller `folder`.

In some way I want to draw the conclusion that the entire part of the base_url will be excluded in the routing process.

It'd be similiar to `$route['\w+/(.+)'] = '$1';` but based on MySQL.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're after now that I read your post again, you want to adjust the routing or the actual `$config['base_url']`? Where is your app and `index.php` located in relation to `domain.com/folder/`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`base_url` has nothing to do with routing, only URLs.

You can use a `pre_controller` hook, `post_controller_constructor` hook, or run it in a base controller `__construct` (such as `MY_Controller`).

It's this easy:

```
// Fetch base_url from database...
$this->config->set_item('base_url', $new_base_url);
```

Functions like `base_url()` read from the CI `$config` array, so you can change it at any time.

Comment: Hmm now that you mention it, I guess that's the case. Would it be possible to make a .htaccess or similiar allow both _domain.com/folder1/_ and _domain.com/folder2/_ to be run from _domain.com/index.php_ based on a certain domain name?

Comment: What's the context here? You have two installations you want to run on the same system files? What is the actual condition you need to check?

Comment: I have one CodeIgniter package, which at the moment I use profiles for several domains, subdomains and I wish to be able to use profiles for folders in the domains aswell. However the routing fetches from the root of the site instead of relevant folder.

Comment: I think you could handle it by hacking `index.php` to change the `$application_path` based on the URI. Give it a shot, should be pretty straight forward. Everything you need to know is in `$_SERVER`.

Comment: I'm having a bit of a pickle figuring out exactly how to do this. I don't think changing the application_path is the solution, since then it'd try to fetch a file that doesn't exist?

Comment: I guess I don't understand what you're doing, I thought you had multiple applications. A detailed explanation and example would help immensely. *"get data from MySQL through HTTP_POST and use and set the base_url"* is particularly confusing.

Comment: I updated, so that you hopefully get what I'm trying to achieve. Sorry if I've been misleading.

Comment: Per your update: did you make sure to allow `folder` in your htaccess so it doesn't get routed through index.php?

Comment: I somewhat solved it. Figured out why it wasn't working, what would be needed to be done, and decided that it wasn't worth doing.